# Block Google tracking on refuse consent of the user with plugin

Tags: plugins, cookies

I use a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-notice/) to display Cookie Notice and I try to block google tracking on refuse content. In the plugin description says that

> USAGE: If you’d like to code a functionality depending on the cookie
>   notice value use the function below:
>
> if ( function_exists('cn_cookies_accepted') && cn_cookies_accepted() )
>   {
>       // Your third-party non functional code here }

So I placed on the given box of the plugin, the following:

```
<script>
if ( function_exists('cn_cookies_accepted') && !cn_cookies_accepted() ) {
    window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-1'] = true; 
}
</script>
```

*where UA-XXXXXX-1 is my Google Analytics Id*

However, I get on the console that:

> ReferenceError: function_exists is not defined

I am thinking that the above code is not Javascript... (may be php ?). So I am stuck... How I proceed?

[image]

Comment: You're right, the `function_exists(..)` snippet is PHP. I guess this is meant to accept PHP that e.g. echos the GA script into the page. I'd ask the plugin authors for a concrete examples of what to use. (Although I see [you've posted on their forum already](https://dfactory.eu/support/topic/script-to-block-google-analytics/), and [someone else who asked for concrete examples didn't get anywhere](https://dfactory.eu/support/topic/examples-for-non-functional-cookies-javascript-code/) :-/  )

Comment: Looking at the plugin, it [emits the 'script blocking' code into the page as HTML](https://github.com/dfactoryplugins/cookie-notice/blob/aa3f9d3080de9c177d2e70bb2b636ba9f9d9d150/cookie-notice.php#L1664) and looks like it's intended to contain script tags, same as you've written. It's only written if cookies are accepted, i.e. there's no need to check for cn_cookies_accepted() in this block. It's possible cn_cookies_accepted was meant for other plugins to use in their code to decide whether to enqueue scripts or not, and isn't relevant for this box.